# “.path()” doesn't work when building geo uri for Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I got a problem about the map intent, I found that the `.path()` doesn't work when building the geo uri, it just opens the google map and does nothing. See the code below:

```
public void onClickOpenAddressButton(View v) {
    String address = "200 w 40th st, new york, ny 10018";

    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();

    uriBuilder.scheme("geo");
    uriBuilder.path("440.749841, -73.986675");
    //uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("q", address);

    showMap(uriBuilder.build());
}

private void showMap(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setData(uri);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't find any Application to handle this Intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But if I use String concatenation with `Uri.parse()` method it works:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + geoLocation));
```

So, if I use the uri builder method and I also have the exact address, do I still need the `.path()` to build a valid geo uri? If so, what is the purpose of `.path()`? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I still need the ".path()" to build a valid geo uri?

No.

> If so, what is the purpose of ".path()"?

There are other types of `Uri` schemes. For example, `https` is a `Uri` scheme, and this is a `Uri` using that scheme:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331195/path-doesnt-work-when-building-geo-uri-for-intent
```

The `path()` of this `Uri` is `/questions/57331195/path-doesnt-work-when-building-geo-uri-for-intent`.

Not all `Uri` values use all possible features of a `Uri`, and so a `Uri` that you build via `Uri.Builder` will not use all possible `Builder` methods.